# How to use hand drawn shapes as a Background for a div?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, animation, svg

I currently am trying to create a navigation-bar which has a hand drawn cloud as a background, but i can't figure out how to make sure the cloud is always visible and looks good on responsive web design.

I tried using just a div with background-image set to the image, but sometimes the cloud is not really visible, sometimes it just gets cut off and so on. I am just hoping for a good and reliable solution for this problem.

[image]

Comment: SVG is your answer

Comment: You need to add some technical details and code if you want a good answer. At the moment, the answer you are asking for is "you have put the image into the background in a way where it is not cut off."

Comment: There are quite a few things that need designing here - what is it to look like on a narrow screen with say aspect ratio 1/4, or a very wide viewport with aspect ratio 10/1 etc. Is all the image to always be visible, in which case fitting it as contain or....

Comment: (Is that image a poorly inked bottom?)